# How to backup alf_data directory in Alfresco

Tags: backup, alfresco

I want to Upgrade Alfresco from 3.4 to 4.0 
What should I do to Backup contentstore directory and contentstore.deleted directory .

Answer (score 3):

From the Alfresco [upgrade documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/upgrade-process.html) and [backing up documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/backup-intro.html) you need to :

1. Shut down your alfresco
2. Save the database and copy the contenstore repository somewhere as a single unit

because the database and contentstore are related.

You can make as well a backup of the Solr index, but this is optional since they can be recreated from the database and contentstore.