# How to move alfresco community addtion from One Ubuntu machine to another ubuntu machine without lose of data?

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco and I am using alfresco community addition 5.0 for document management system.Upto now I don't have any problem.

now my doubt is how to move alfresco community from one system to another system without lose of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to look at the [Backing up and restoring](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ch-backup-restore.html) part of the Alfresco documentation.

To make it simple, you have data stored as three parts :

1. The **database** which can be backed up and dumped in an other postgresql of your choice
2. The **contentstore** which contains the files data of your system can be copied and pasted in your new system (of course with appropriated permissions).
3. The **index** which contains your indexed content to make powefull search. The transfert of this one is optional since it can be regenerated from the database and contentstore

Of course, you should do your backup and transfert with your alfresco stopped, [since database, contentstore and index are related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38615099/4167384).